# Wordpress Comments with ACF plugin - How do i show the info on the comments area?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, advanced-custom-fields

I installed ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) and created a filed group (with 2 fields: star_rating & personality) to show only with the normal Wordpress comments area. and everything works perfectly.

----- Example: https://snipboard.io/NMbm0B.jpg

The issue is that I dont know how to show those 2 fields in the front of the page. So WP comments show Avatar, Name, text, and date ONLY. It does not show "Star Rating" or "Personality". But I can see the info on the back-end inside each comment.

---- Example: https://snipboard.io/EdtrV3.jpg

So can i call or show these fields that are saved on the commentmeta table database????? using php or blocks or whatever :)

Thank you so much!!!!!!

i tried this code given to me by my hosting company but the guy didnt know too much about Wordpress

if ($result->meta_key == 'star_rating' || $result->meta_key == 'personality') {
echo $result->meta_key . ': ' . $result->meta_value . '
';
}

but it is not working. I dont know so much of PHP but I tried the code on functions.php and also comments.php